# laravel отношения

Tags: php, laravel, relation, связи

Здравствуйте. У меня есть модели и таблицы Complex, Floors со следующими структурами:

complex - complex_id, number, descriptiom
floors - floor_id, complex_id, number, description

В модели Complex делаю связь один ко многим (один комплекс может иметь несколько этажей):

```
public function floors(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Floors', 'complex_id');
}
```

В модели Floors делаю обратное отношение:

```
public function complex(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Complex', 'complex_id');
}
```

Пытаюсь получить все этажи первого комплекса:

```
Complex::first()->floors();
```

Результат - пустой. Что может быть неправильно?

Comment: а если так `Complex::first()->floors` ?

Comment: То же самое, пустой массив. Данные в таблицах есть, проверял

Comment: Указание локального ключа тоже не дало никакого эффекта

Comment: $this->hasMany('App\Floors', 'complex_id', 'complex_id'); ?

Comment: Да, $this->hasMany('App\Floors', 'complex_id', 'complex_id') работает, спасибо большое.

Comment: Это частая ошибка, посмотри внимательно на тип возвращаемый функцией `Complex::first()->floors();` это будет по факту ресурс, от него тогда нужно брать `Complex::first()->floors()->get()`, а если пишешь как свойство, то при помощи магического фреймворк преобразует все за тебя.